# Texto vertical com css (90º)

Tags: html, css

Estou transformando um documento word em html, porém não sei como fazer para escrever o texto dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia como?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar `transform: rotate(270deg)` para deixar o texto na vertical conforme a imagem.

Comment: Obrigado @RaimundoNorberto, funcionou aqui com 270deg

Comment: Desculpa, valor errado, vou arrumar... =)

Answer (score 4):

Fora o rotate (que irá modificar todo o div) se você quiser apenas alterar a escrita, sem afetar o `background`, `border` e espaçamentos, você pode usar o `writing-mode`.

O vem por padrão como `horizontal-tb`, e terá as seguinte opções:

### horizontal-tb

O conteúdo segue horizontalmente da esquerda para a direita e na vertical de cima para baixo. A próxima linha horizontal está posicionado abaixo da linha anterior.

```css
.foo { writing-mode: horizontal-tb; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
Olá mundo novo!<br>
Quebra de linha
</div>
```

### vertical-rl

O conteúdo segue verticalmente de cima para baixo e horizontalmente da direita para a esquerda. A linha vertical ao lado está posicionada à esquerda da linha anterior.

```css
.foo { writing-mode: vertical-rl; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
Olá mundo novo!<br>
Quebra de linha
</div>
```

### vertical-lr

O conteúdo segue verticalmente de cima para baixo, na horizontal da esquerda para a direita. A linha vertical seguinte é posicionada à direita da linha anterior.

```css
.foo { writing-mode: vertical-lr; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">
Olá mundo novo!<br>
Quebra de linha
</div>
```

Também existe a propriedade `direction`, que suporta os valores `ltr` (esquerda para direita) e `rtl` (direita para esquerda), mas isto é usado geralmente para textos com caracteres de diferentes linhagens (o que pode-se ser util se combinado com `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`).

Sem `unicode-bibi`:

```css
.foo { direction: ltr; }
.baz { direction: rtl; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">Olá mundo novo!</div>
<div class="baz">Olá mundo novo!</div>
```

Com `unicode-bidi`:

```css
.foo {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
.baz {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Olá mundo novo!</div>
<div class="baz">Olá mundo novo!</div>
```

> - *Note* que ainda existem o `sideways-rl` e `sideways-lr` (provavelmente era este que você necessitava), mas são experimentais e não é suportado por todos navegadores.
> - Note também que os valores `lr`, `lr-tb`, `rl` e `tb-rl` estão em desuso, mas ainda são suportados pelo SVG1 ou para navegadores mais antigos:

Comment: Muito legal também!

Answer (score 2):

Outra sugestão.

```css
.textovertical{
    width:1px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; 
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="textovertical">
Olá esse é um texto vertical !
</p>
```

Comment: Boa tbm, acabei de ver que vou precisar de algo assim também em breve rs

Comment: É, a princípio é diferente do que pede, mas se for precisar usar para idiomas escritos na vertical, ai vai...