# Dúvida sobre orientação de texto no CSS

Tags: css, css3

Eu tenho um botão que está na vertical, portanto o texto fica na vertical também, queria saber se tem alguma propriedade nativa do CSS que faça o texto ficar letra por letra na horizontal porém em coluna mesmo, um abaixo do outro como no exemplo na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu formulei uma sugestão sem precisar de transform: [Texto vertical com css (90º)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151375/3635), apesar que transform também poderá atender, a diferença é que o write-mode tem um pouco mais de suporte e o controle é sobre o "texto" ao invés do elemento, mas depende do que você deseja.

Comment: É, testei aqui e deu certo valeuzão mano